# CI on cumulated values

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have measured the emission of `acetone` and acetaldehyde`from two`soil_types`:` A`and`B`three times across 94`days```.

I have calculated and visualized the cumulated emission over time, however I am having issues putting CI 95% Bands (+/-2 SD) or even simple error bars would do.

This is what I've managed to do:

```
df_cum <- df%>%
  group_by(soil_type, compound, days)%>%
  summarise(mean=mean(emission))%>%
  mutate(cum_emission=cumsum(mean)) 


  plot <- ggplot(df_cum, aes(x = days, y = cum_emission, colour=soil_type)) + 
    geom_line(size = 1)+
    geom_point()+
    scale_colour_manual(values=c("#00AFBB", "brown")) + 
    scale_size_manual(values=c(8.4, 1.7))+
    labs(x = "Time (days)", 
         y = "Cumulated production (umol/g dw soil)", 
         title = "Cumulated production") + 
    labs(shape="", color="") +
    facet_wrap(~compound)+
    theme_bw()
```

Giving this:

[image]

I'm hoping to do be able to put error bars in my plot or do a plot similar to this one with CI:

[image]

The data looks like this:

```
df <- structure(list(days = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 94, 
94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 
94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94), soil = c(6, 6, 12, 12, 2, 
2, 1, 1, 14, 14, 4, 4, 33, 33, 38, 38, 34, 34, 37, 37, 36, 36, 
13, 13, 32, 32, 5, 5, 3, 3, 35, 35, 6, 6, 12, 12, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
14, 14, 4, 4, 33, 33, 38, 38, 34, 34, 37, 37, 36, 36, 13, 13, 
32, 32, 5, 5, 3, 3, 35, 35, 6, 6, 12, 12, 2, 2, 4, 4, 33, 33, 
38, 38, 34, 34, 37, 37, 36, 36, 13, 13, 5, 5, 3, 3, 35, 35), 
    soil_type = c("B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", 
    "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
    "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
    "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
    "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", 
    "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"), compound = c("Acetone", 
    "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", 
    "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", 
    "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", 
    "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", 
    "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", 
    "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", 
    "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", 
    "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", 
    "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", 
    "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", 
    "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", 
    "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", 
    "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", 
    "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", 
    "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", 
    "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", 
    "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", 
    "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde"), emission = c(0.001, 
    0.001, 0.009, 0.004, 0.029, 0.032, 0.066, 0.057, 0.015, 0.015, 
    0, 0.003, 0.015, 0.011, 0.016, 0.005, 0.046, 0.011, 0.004, 
    0.005, 0.015, 0.003, 0.025, 0.012, 0.001, 0.001, 0.004, 0, 
    0.012, 0.002, 0.003, 0.002, 0.006, 0, 0.008, 0.001, 0.061, 
    0.055, 0.076, 0.056, 0.056, 0.074, 0, 0, 0.018, 0.02, 0.015, 
    0.001, 0.064, 0, 0.012, 0.004, 0.009, 0, 0.399, 0.037, 0.002, 
    0.001, 0.116, 0, 0.139, 0, 0.004, 0.001, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.001, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.001, 0.005, 
    0.001, 0, 0.002, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -90L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
new_df <- structure(list(daysincubated4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), soil = c(6L, 6L, 12L, 12L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 14L, 
14L, 4L, 4L, 13L, 13L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 12L, 12L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 14L, 14L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 12L, 12L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
14L, 14L, 4L, 4L, 13L, 13L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 13L, 13L, 5L, 5L, 
3L, 3L), soil_type = c("SOC<10", "SOC<10", "SOC>10", "SOC>10", 
"SOC<10", "SOC<10", "SOC<10", "SOC<10", "SOC>10", "SOC>10", "SOC<10", 
"SOC<10", "SOC>10", "SOC>10", "SOC>10", "SOC>10", "SOC<10", "SOC<10", 
"SOC<10", "SOC<10", "SOC>10", "SOC>10", "SOC<10", "SOC<10", "SOC<10", 
"SOC<10", "SOC>10", "SOC>10", "SOC<10", "SOC<10", "SOC<10", "SOC<10", 
"SOC>10", "SOC>10", "SOC<10", "SOC<10", "SOC<10", "SOC<10", "SOC>10", 
"SOC>10", "SOC<10", "SOC<10", "SOC>10", "SOC>10", "SOC>10", "SOC>10", 
"SOC<10", "SOC<10", "SOC>10", "SOC>10", "SOC>10", "SOC>10", "SOC<10", 
"SOC<10"), compound = c("Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", 
"Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", 
"Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", 
"Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", 
"Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", 
"Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", 
"Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", 
"Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", 
"Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", 
"Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", 
"Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", 
"Acetaldehyde"), emission = c(0.0011, 0.001, 0.0094, 0.0042, 
0.0289, 0.0318, 0.0656, 0.0571, 0.0152, 0.0146, 0, 0.0033, 0.0247, 
0.0117, 0.0038, 3e-04, 0.0124, 0.0016, 8e-04, 1e-04, 0.0188, 
0.0139, 0.0728, 0.0818, 0.0883, 0.0731, 0.0251, 0.0774, 0, 0, 
0.0061, 2e-04, 0.0084, 7e-04, 0.061, 0.0551, 0.0761, 0.0559, 
0.0563, 0.0742, 0, 0, 0.3989, 0.0367, 0.1163, 4e-04, 0.1386, 
4e-04, 0.0461, 0.0495, 0.089, 0.001, 0.1414, 0.001)), row.names = c(NA, 
-54L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: you have n=1 for every data point, how can you get confidence interval? The plot you showed, most likely it plots the cumulative average of many values

Comment: I have 10 soils of soil_type A, and 6 soils of soil_type B. Each of the soils have been measured for acetone and acetaldehyde emission on three time points. I'm sure I'm forgetting something or explaning poorly since no one is understanding me, however I not sure what you mean by n=1. I would mean n=10 for soil_type A and n=6 for soil_type B. In reality there are many more soils.

Comment: Of course I only have n=1 after I have summarized the data if that's what you mean. But my problem is that I can't calculate the confidence interval from the original df for each soil type and each compound and present it in a graph.

Comment: sorry my bad. just saw that you provided the full data frame. yeah you need to calculate it first. I try to write something for it now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, you basically need to estimate the confidence interval for your cumulative line for soil type in different compound, if we look at your data:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=days,y=cumsum(emission),col=soil_type)) + 
geom_line() + facet_grid(compound ~ soil) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

What you want to do is estimate the error across lines of the same color in the same row (compound). To do this, we exclude 1 and 14 from your example since it is incomplete. Basically we are trying to convert all your measurements to cumulative, grouped by soil x compound.

We can use `stat_summary()` to calculate the mean and se:

```
df %>% filter(!soil %in% c(1,14)) %>% 
group_by(soil,compound) %>% 
mutate(c_emission = cumsum(emission)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = days, y = c_emission, col=soil_type,fill=soil_type)) + 
stat_summary(geom="line", fun = mean) + 
stat_summary(geom="ribbon",alpha=0.05,linetype="dotted")+ 
facet_wrap(~compound)
```

[image]

What we are plotting above is the mean at every time point, + 1* standard error. If you want the 95% confidence interval

```
df %>% filter(!soil %in% c(1,14)) %>% 
group_by(soil,compound) %>% 
mutate(c_emission = cumsum(emission)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = days, y = c_emission, col=soil_type,fill=soil_type)) +
stat_summary(geom="line",fun = mean) + 
stat_summary(geom="ribbon",alpha=0.05,linetype="dotted",
fun.data = mean_cl_normal)+ 
facet_wrap(~compound)
```

[image]

The confidence interval is huge because your standard error is large.. Might be better when you have more samples.

Comment: Yes, that looks great @StupidWolf! Do you know how to show CI with shades?

Comment: well, you don't include  `fill=` in `ggplot(aes(...fill=soil_type`, but do `stat_summary(geom="ribbon",fill=..)` and you add the color you want to shade with? or you don't want the line?

Comment: So, using the code you provide in your answer I get the correct plot, however with this warning ```No summary function supplied, defaulting to `mean_se()``` . When I try to do as you suggest in your comment I get this error message ```Error in layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = StatSummary, geom = geom,  : 
  objekt 'soil_type' was not found```

Comment: I did like this:                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
```df %>% filter(!soil %in% c(1,14)) %>% 
  group_by(soil,compound) %>% 
  mutate(c_emission = cumsum(emission)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = days, y = c_emission, col=soil_type)) + 
  stat_summary(geom="line", fun = mean) + 
  stat_summary(geom="ribbon",fill=soil_type, alpha=0.05,linetype="dotted")+ 
  facet_wrap(~compound)```

Comment: the `fill=soil_type` has to be inside `aes()` .. what do you actually mean by show CI with shades? The plot i showed has a shaded ribbon right

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'm colorblind and didn't see the shading until I changed the color! How can I remove the line?

Comment: Hi again @StupidWolf, I cannot make the code work with my actual data. I made a new dummy dataset in my original question that experience the same problem when running the code. The problem is that days are not ordered correctly and the cumulated values therefore are faulty. Do you have any idea as how to fix this?

Comment: can you order your data frame by days first? `df = df[order(df$days),]`

Answer (score 1):

To plot error bars, have you already tried with

```
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = y- 2*sd, xmax = y+ 2*sd), width = .1, position=position_dodge(.9))
```

with `sd` being your standard deviation? you can calculate it in the `mutate(...)` part of the code. I am afraid, though, that you don't have enough replicates to calculate sd/CI. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment @Ubiminor. I'm not sure I can make your suggestion work though. The data provided here is just a small sub sample of my actual data.